# Yield to other threads/tasks in OpenMP

Tags: c++, cuda, openmp

I want to use OpenMP with CUDA to achieve overlapping kernel executions. Ther kernel calls are all asynchronous, but I have very little code between launches so the individual OpenMP threads tend to block as they try to launch another kernel, or do a mem copy (I don't always have mem copys right after the call so async mem copys aren't necessarily the solution). I would like a way to signal to the OpenMP schedular to switch to another OpenMP thread. Is this possible in OpenMP?

Example:

```
int main() {
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
       for(int j=0;j<10;j++) {
           //call kernel here

           // ---->   Would like to signal to continue with other  
           //           threads as next call will block

           //copy data from kernel
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a thread blocks, the operating system's scheduler should automatically switch to another runnable thread (if one is available), so you shouldn't need to do anything.

However, if all your OpenMP program is doing is calling CUDA kernels, it's likely that the GPU is the bottleneck, so you won't get much benefit from using threads on the CPU anyway.  It may not be worth using OpenMP at all.

If you do continue using OpenMP, though, you should probably add a `collapse(2)` to that `omp parallel for`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, the code presented is a very contrived example of the sort of work I'm doing. The actual code is not merely stacked for loops. Could you elaborate on the switching? Is this only on a thread level (so restricted to the OpenMP thread count) or is it more of a "job" level. Not sure if I'm making myself clear: I don't know a lot about the implementations of OpenMP

Comment: I'm talking about at the OS thread level, since you asked about switching to another OpenMP thread and OpenMP threads (presumably) correspond to native OS threads.  If you're saying now that you have more OpenMP tasks than threads, take a look at the OMP `taskyield` and `taskwait` directives.  However, that sort of approach isn't optimal:  the yield may "return" too soon and you still waste CPU time waiting for the kernel to finish, or it may take too long and you waste GPU time by not submitting a new kernel quickly enough.

Comment: That's great! Just what I was looking for. I will give it a try. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: If you really want to avoid wasting CPU time, you could use a loop that repeatedly checks whether the kernel is done and yields if not.  That'll keep the CPU busy, at the cost of possibly leaving the GPU idle while it waits for the CPU to notice that the kernel has finished.  But again, the GPU is likely to be the bottleneck.